# Given an array $A$ and an index $i$, prove there always exists a subarray whose sum $\pmod {i} = 0$.

Tags: combinatorics

> Given is an array $A$ of positive integers with size $n$ and an array index $i$ (indexing starts at $1$). Prove using mathematical induction over $n$ that there always exists a contiguous subarray $S$ in $A$ such that the (sum of the elements of $S$) $\pmod {i} = 0.$

I get stuck halfway through the inductive step. Here is my work:

Let $p(n)$ denote the statement we're proving.

*Base case*: For $n = 1$ the statement holds (every positive integer mod $1 = 0$), so the subarray $S$ is the array $A$ itself.

*Induction assumption*: Suppose $p(n)$ is true.

*Inductive step*: For an array of size $n+1$ we consider the following two cases:

Case (1): $i \in \{1, 2, ..., n\}$. It follows directly from the *inductive assumption* that $p(n+1)$ is true (since $i \neq n+1$).

Case (2): $i = n+1$ (...).

This is where I get stuck, how would you argue that $S$ exists here?

Comment: I usually see this problem solved using the pigeonhole principle, I also do not see how induction would work.

Comment: This is the same as the "donation problem" that was posted several times yesterday, isn't it? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3713283/complicated-problem-involving-mathematical-induction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have left is case $(2)$. This case cannot (as far as I can tell) be solved inductively, but it can be solved with the pigeonhole principle. I will give you a hint as to how this can be done.

The sum of a contiguous sub-array can be written as the difference of two prefix sums, e.g,
$$
a_3+a_4+a_5=(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5)-(a_1+a_2)
$$
Furthermore, the contiguous sum is equivalent $\pmod {n+1}$ to zero if and only if  the two prefix sums are equivalent to each other $\pmod {n+1}$. So you just need to show there exist two equal prefix sums. The pigeonhole principle naturally applies to showing there exist two equal things...

Comment: For this to work, wouldn't I need *more* prefix sums than there is? As far as I understand, an array of size $n$ has $n$ prefix sums. In order to use the pigeonhole principle, we'd need more prefix sums "than we can fit". How do I get this last sum? Sorry if I'm totally misunderstanding this

Comment: @Maddow You are right, that is a problem you must overcome! You will see what happens if you look at a small example; find a list of length $4$ whose prefix sums are all different modulo $4$, see why this still has a consecutive sum which is $0$ modulo $4$, then generalize.

Comment: I have updated my question, can you please check my work?

Comment: @Maddow That's it!